# Files copied to flashdrive only on unmount

Tags: debian, mount, usb-drive, flash-memory

I use Debian wheezy with KDE4. Most of the time when I copy something to a flashdrive, the write does not actually take place until I unmount. This even happens with relatively large amounts of data (i think some music around 100MB was still buffered until unmount).

Is there any way to tell the OS to write immediately when I tell it to write so I don't have to worry too much about removing my flashdrive without properly unmounting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by [arranging for the device to be mounted with the `sync` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/files-copied-to-flashdrive-only-on-unmount/21630#21630). But it's not such a good idea, because this can wear cheap USB flash drives very fast (this has been [discussed on the Linux kernel mailing list](http://readlist.com/lists/vger.kernel.org/linux-kernel/22/111748.html)).

Recent versions of Linux have the `flush` option for FAT filesystems, which is somewhere between `sync` and `async`: it causes all delayed writes to be flushed as soon as the disk becomes inactive. The `flush` option is on by default in Ubuntu 10.04, but not in Debian wheezy.

See also [Should I unmount a USB drive before unplugging it?](https://superuser.com/questions/180722/should-i-unmount-a-usb-drive-before-unplugging-it/180732#180732)

Answer (score 3):

The `mount` command has two related options:

> sync    All I/O to the filesystem should be done synchronously.
>
> dirsync All directory updates within the filesystem should be done synchronously.

You can specify them in the `mount` command's `-o` option:

```
mount -o sync /mnt/flashdrive
```

Or in your `/etc/fstab`'s fourth column:

> `/dev/sdb1   /mnt/flashdrive   auto   rw,user,noauto,sync    0   0`

Comment: -o flush is preferable to -o sync, as sync will waste time and put more wear and tear on the disk performing every single trivial write, which can wear out the FAT sooner.  Flush just makes sure the writing is all done when the file is closed.

Comment: You are right. As I remember I never met flash drive with other filesystem than FAT.