# USB copy hangs for a while when reach the 100%

Tags: gnome3, usb-drive, file-copy, debian

When I copy files of a considerable size (for example right now one of 689MB) to a USB stick, the copy hangs at 100% for 5 min or more.

I have tried both Nautilus and `rsync --progress`. With the former it seems that never ends and I have to kill nautilus. With the latter it ends, but as I said, 5 minutes or more after it has reached the 100%.

I'm using Wheezy 64 bits and Gnome Shell.

If I'm not mistaken, there is a reported bug about the Nautilus issue, but why is it happening with rsync too?

Comment: I'm getting this as well, under Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I think Linux is buffering the data until some final synchronous operation at the end.

If you mount it as a syncronous filesystem, then it should give a more realistic copy progress indicator:

[Files copied to flashdrive only on unmount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/files-copied-to-flashdrive-only-on-unmount/21630#21630)

Comment: Reading that question I realize about something: I'm using flush. As said in that question, it should copy when it's inactive. However since it reaches 100%, it becomes inactive (at least no light).

Comment: Sadly, a comment on the linked answer states "sync will waste time and put more wear and tear on the disk performing every single trivial write, which can wear out the FAT sooner." It's very annoying!