# etx3 on USB flash stick not flushed on unmount / eject via Cinnamon / Nemo GUI (ext4 / cli umount ext3 - ok)

Tags: usb-drive, cinnamon

Changes (written file, changed permissions) are gone if `ext3` formatted `USB` stick is unmounted / ejected via `Cinnamon` / `Nemo` GUI, if via bash `umount` - changes remain.

I've been using `Cinnamon` for several years now and if my memory serves me right, I faced similar issue with `ext4` too (today changes to `ext4` formatted removable drive remain upon removal / reinsertion), therefore I'd like to investigate root cause.

TL;DR

I formatted USB flash to ext3 to be able to set permissions. Just now I did it several times with same result and reinsertion to different, then same linux computer:

- copy a file to USB flash via Nemo (result - file is visible in Nemo on the USB drive)
- unmount / eject (tried both) via Nemo / icon on a desktop
- remove, reinsert (result - no file visible)

System(s) Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, file manager Nemo. It could be a transient glitch, but IMHO nasty one (I don't want to recheck success of file copy by reinserting USB every time). While it is reproducible, I'd like to find out root cause. Please advise what to try, I was not able to find such issue via googling.

I've found [Files copied to flashdrive only on unmount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21628/files-copied-to-flashdrive-only-on-unmount) and https://superuser.com/questions/180722/should-i-unmount-a-usb-drive-before-unplugging-it/180732#180732 and my understanding that unmounting should result in data written to USB.

Note: the file was just created and is copied seemingly momentarily (from a cache).

Note2: there is alarmingly no usual notification that USB drive can be removed, but in bash mount does not show that usb anymore. The file is not large (200mb) to take a lot of time to write to usb IMHO, it is just not being written at all (it is a hypothesis) and remain in cache only even when umount is performed.

ADDED 3:

I've tried copying the file to another USB stick. First, it was formatted as FAT32, it went as expected, file remained after removal/reinsertion, then I reformatted that stick to EXT3 (same as initial drive) and again on copying and removal file disappeared (as expected now).
https://superuser.com/questions/180722/should-i-unmount-a-usb-drive-before-unplugging-it/180732#180732

> Recent versions introduce the flush option for FAT filesystems, which
> is somewhere in between (flush all delayed writes as soon as the disk
> becomes inactive); it's on by default in Ubuntu 10.04.

ADDED 4:

I've tried to `umount` via CLI, `it thought` for several seconds and file remained. BTW, I noted permissions change also disappeared when GUI eject was used. So looks like Cinnamon or Nemo issue. I like Cinnamon overall, how can I investigate further?

Comment: Try to analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), If you are lucky, there is 'only confusion', and you should be able to find a way to verify, that things work. But it is also possible that the USB drive is failing (at an early stage of failure).

Comment: @sudodus. on FAT32 stick file remained, on EXT3 not (same as initial issue) - see ADDED 3.

Comment: I have good experience of using ext4, which is a newer version of ext file system. And I have good experience of gparted creating ext4 on USB pendrives. Please try to (install and) use gparted to create an ext4 file system and use that file system instead of ext3. - By the way, how are you unmounting the file system before unplugging the drive?

Comment: Guess: The filesystem is mounted in more than one location (automounter?), and you are only unmounting one location? Verify with output of `mount`. Also, try `umount` from the shell. For me, that blocks when data to an USB stick is not fully written, and returns as soon as it is.

Comment: You can check if things work better with ext4 (than with ext3). And you can make it a habit to umount with `sudo umount` before unplugging, or at least run `sync` and wait for the prompt, which indicates that all buffers are flushed and all changes are written to the USB drive's memory cells.

Comment: @dirkt, I've undated the question, both cli umount and ext4 GUI eject - ok. USB are automounted `uhelper=udisks2`. Any idea why ext3 + GUI produce problems?

Comment: @sudodus, yes, this way (cli) works ok. But IMHO many Linux users (including myself) like to use (and rely on!) GUI sometimes ;-)

Comment: I'd assume ext3 is incidental (it's just a timing thing that by chance doesn't happen to FAT), and the GUI has a buggy implementation. The only way to find out is to investigate what the GUI does by looking at the code, and spot the bug. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @sudodus, the reason why I chose ext3 is that some time ago I made removable drive and was not able to open it on older Linux, I've read then journaling changed in newer kernel. Now I thought if I choose older file system, there is less change it won't be readable. Do you know ways to ensure ext4 would open on older kernels?

Comment: It seems there is a problem with a graphical (GUI) tool in your case. If this is important, and you want to use a GUI tool, you should consider another desktop environment and or GUI tool, for example Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or one of the Ubuntu family flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, ... Xubuntu). I don't think anyone can ensure that ext4 can be opened by older kernels. How old? ext4 has been standard in Ubuntu for at least 10 years, illustrated by both answers in [What is the default file system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64147/what-is-the-default-file-system) from AskUbuntu in October 2011.

Comment: @sudodus, they are called ext4 but newer journaling is not backward compatible. I think I might use LM 17 for some PCs (kernel 3.x), and just checked creating drives on new kernel 5.x with Gnome Disks Utility - ext3 drive opened on 3.x, but ext4 has not.

Comment: Please notice that the oldest Linux Mint version that is supported today is 19 Tara. See [this link](https://linuxmint.com/download_all.php). There are security issues with version 17 because it has passed end of life and no longer receives updates.

Comment: I can understand that you want ext3. But there seems to be some trade-off. Maybe that you keep the current systems, but change your habits in order to make sure that the buffers are flushed before unplugging usb pendrives. Maybe that you change something else and can get along without using command line tools. Is it possible for you to upgrade the old LM 17 systems?